# Does iBeacon work on Android?

Tags: android, ibeacon

Can I have my iBeacon send push notifications to Android devices? If so what are the Android version and device limitations?

(The reason I am asking here is because this question still isn't easily found on fast google search.)

Comment: This has been answered here many times before - there are a number of links in the sidebar of this very page.

Comment: i am aware of that and the answer, however google disagrees.

Comment: We don't allow asking duplicates for SEO.  Also, your search might have failed for its fundamental misconception: iBeacons don't send push notifications, even on iOS - rather they signal to app functionality, which might include requesting and displaying a notification from some cooperating server.

Answer (score 12):

**The simple answer is yes.**  A few caveats:

1. Only Android version 4.3+ supports Bluetooth LE, which is needed to detect beacons.
2. The Android device must have a Bluetooth LE chipset.  Most devices released in late 2012 or later have this feature.
3. You need a third party library bundled with your app, like the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/), or you need to roll your own code to decode Bluetooth LE advertisements to read beacon identifiers.

You should also understand that beacons themselves don't actually push notifications to devices.  Mobile devices can detect beacons, and when they do, they read their numeric identifier.  A user-facing notification is often triggered upon beacon detection programmatically by tying the beacon's numeric identifier to a string message like "Welcome to our store."

Comment: Please don't reward blatant, knowing duplicates with answers.